# XC32 migrating from 1.32 to 1.34

Tags: c, embedded, legacy, mplab, pic32

I'm using XC32 and MPLABX for work. After a year of projects I've decided to try to upgrade to new XC32 version. I've seen that legacy libraries like plib are no longer supported and I'd like to know if someone have tried to migrate old projects to new Harmony framework and if there is an alternative for all previous libraries.

Could it be a long work the migration from Legacy to Harmony? Is it a safe transition?

Comment: could you migrate? it seems to be still an issue

Answer (score 2):

In v.1.34, you can still link against plib. IIRC the source code is available too. Harmony at present is a horrible contraption, I suggest staying away from it for as long as possible. As far as old projects go, I'd rather archive them together with old tools.